# Can you cancel Shield using readied Dispel Magic?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, reactions

Our paladin attacks an enemy wizard. He used *shield* to block the paladin's attack. Knowing we are dealing with a magic user, I've readied *dispel magic* beforehand when an enemy is casting a spell, and dispel the shield.

**Is the *shield* negated and now the attack hits (and deals damage)?**

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### Yes you could dispel it, but the initial attack would still miss

The DMG has guidance on when Readied actions (and reactions and triggers in general) occur:

> follow whatever timing is specified in the reaction's description. For example, the opportunity attack and the shield spell are clear about the fact that they can interrupt their triggers. **If a reaction has no timing specified, or the timing is unclear, the reaction occurs after its trigger finishes**, as in the Ready action. (DMG p. 252, bold added)

Your *dispel magic* spell could certainly remove the *shield* spell from a target (so they wouldn't have a +5 to AC for the rest of the round): but it could only do so *after* the *shield* spell had been successfully cast. And the casting of the *shield* spell will disrupt the initial attack which triggered it.

**If you want to stop the Shield spell from taking effect at all, use *counterspell*, not *dispel magic***, as suggested in the [Sage Advice Compendium](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf), p. 15 (which also wouldn't require you to Ready a spell, spending both an action and a spell slot before you're sure your enemy even intends to cast a spell).

Comment: @Vylix It does not matter how fast you dispel the shield, because the moment the shield spell is cast is the same moment that the triggering hit is turned into a miss. You need to prevent the casting of shield altogether and to do that you need counterspell.

Comment: However, the paladin doesn't have counterspell, but does have dispel. And prepping the ready action would also mean forgoing their attack for a round which may not be the best choice unless their closing distance and can't attack anyway.

Comment: This answer is basically perfect, but I suggest one addition: note that if readied _dispel magic_ could be used in the way the OP is asking then it would effectively render _counterspell_ obsolete. You strongly imply this, but it might be worth making explicit.

Comment: @Bloodcinder I wouldn't quite go that far: a readied *dispel magic* would still have a higher "opportunity cost" than *counterspell*, since Reading a spell requires a full Action in addition to a Reaction, and requires a spell slot be spent speculatively (and wasted if the enemy doesn't cast a spell this round). But I do agree that it would be odd for the game designers to create the spell *counterspell* if *dispel magic* could work this way.

Comment: *Readying, not "Reading." But you get my meaning.